# In Python, how to use list in dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to fetch a value from a dictionary but the value is a list.

For instances

```
dict_1 = {A:[2,3,4], B:[3,4,5], C:[6,7,8]}
```

Now I am trying to iterate through the dictionary and fetch the value of it, divide by any integer and return the value to form another dictionary

```
dict_2 = {A:[2/x, 3/x, 4/x], B:[3/x, 4/x, 5/x], C:[6/x, 7/x, 8/x]}
```

Comment: understanding the question has become more difficult than answering it.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis The question is how to use a list in dictionary. I read that as how to use a list as a value for a dictionary key. The rest of the post shows that a lot of irrelevant information, but also that the OP already knows how to do that.

Comment: @Anthon Anyway, I am confident this one has been *decoded\decrypted* and answered

Comment: @ev.kounis i tried lot of ways of asking the question , this was only one not rejected.  :) .. my question was to understand when in a dictionary and if list is a value how to use the list or iterate through it..

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a new dictionary, you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
dict_2 = {k: [y/float(x) for y in v] for k, v in dict_1.items()}
```

Otherwise, you could use a *for* loop:

```
for k, v in dict_1.items():
   dict_1[k] = [y/float(x) for y in v]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> from __future__ import division   # only required for python 2 (but doesn't hurt on Python 3)
>>> dict_1 ={'A':[2,3,4],'B':[3,4,5],'C':[6,7,8]}
>>> x = 2
>>> {key: [val/x for val in value] for key, value in dict_1.items()}
{'A': [1.0, 1.5, 2.0], 'B': [1.5, 2.0, 2.5], 'C': [3.0, 3.5, 4.0]}
```